# Does not return data as intended when creating the chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am creating the chart like this:

```
$.getJSON('./menluvas?colt2' + '&colt2=' + colt2, function (data) {
    
    var series = [],
        len = data.length,
        i = 0;
        
     for(i;i<len;i++){
        series.push({
            name: [data[i][0]]
        });
     }
     

     console.log(series);
    
    
    $('#container2').highcharts({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container2',
            type: 'column',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 0,
            beta: 0,
            depth: 20,
        }
        },
        title: {
            text: '' +idf+  ' - AVALIAÇÃO CONSUMOS LUVAS' 
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: series
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Unidade - (1 Caixa = 100 Luvas)'
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            
        }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,  
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Janeiro',
            data: data
            }]
    });
});
```

The `series` variable returns the following values:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
name: ["Vinil s/ pó"]
__proto__: Object
1:
name: ["Latex s/pó"]
__proto__: Object
2:
name: ["Nitrilo"]
__proto__: Object
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

When creating the graph, in xAxis I use the `series` variable.
But the graph does not show the values ​​as above and returns `[object object]`, as shown in the image:

[image]

What I want is that where [object object] returns, you have to return the data of the `series` variable.

Comment: `xAxis.categories` should be an array of strings, meanwhile, you are trying to set it as an array of objects, that's why you get output like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xAxis` expects an array, but you are passing an array of `Objects`, each with a `name` label. You are doing that here:

```
 for(i;i<len;i++){
    series.push({
        name: [data[i][0]]
    });
 }
```

Instead, you would need something like:

```
 for(i;i<len;i++){
    series.push(data[i][0]);
 }
```

*I have not tested the code*.